# How do I customise the drag/drop insertion marker on an NSTableView or NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I am implementing drag and drop functionality on an NSOutlineView. I want to support dropping between rows and dropping *on* a row.

I am currently setting the draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle to 'regular' which by default gives a row highlight when dragging on to a row, and a circle-and-blue-bar insertion marker when dragging between the rows.

I can customise the drawing when dropping on a row by overriding drawDraggingDestinationFeedback on NSTableRowView.

I cannot see a way of customising the blue insertion marker though.

Is there a place to override this drawing, or do I have to set the draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle to 'none' and do everything manually - perhaps with my own views over the NSOutlineView?

Comment: I'm trying to do this very thing. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Hey Clifton. I never found a place to customise this drawing. I ended up with spacer rows in my outliner which actually only impacted a couple of points in my code.